# Checking if attribute exists and is truthy in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

I am new to Python. I find myself doing this quite a lot:

```
if 'input_url' in inputparams and inputparams['input_url']:
    # do something with inputparams['input_url']

if 'output_url' in inputparams and inputparams['output_url']:
    # do something with inputparams['output_url']
```

I am using this as an equivalent to checking $_GET variables in PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['var']) && $_GET['var']) { do_action(); }
```

Is there a better way of doing this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.get(key)` returns `None` if the key is not found. So if `inputparams` is a `dict`, then

```
if 'input_url' in inputparams and inputparams['input_url']:
```

can be simplified to:

```
if inputparams.get('input_url'):
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks a lot better!